# Delete an element if has same value with another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution about hiding a div if its span has same value with another span.

For instance, from the code bellow, I want to hide div.priceWithoutTax in case that div.priceWithoutTax span has same value with div.salesPrice span

```
<div class="PriceBox" id="productPrice">
    <div class="ProdPriceBoxRedInner">
        <div class="salesPrice" style="display : block;">
            <span class="salesPrice">20,00 €</span>
        </div>
        <div class="PriceAdditional" style="top: 0px; display: none;">
            <div class="priceWithoutTax" style="display : block;">
                <span class="priceWithoutTax">20,00 €</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be noted that it's really `div.priceWithoutTax`, as those are classes !

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I feel a bit dizzy.

Comment: And you're not using jQuery ?

Comment: if($("span.salesPrice").text()===$("span.priceWithoutTax").text()){
   $("div.priceWithoutTax").hide();
}

Comment: @ChakravarthySM I tried your code and it works. Thank you all dudes for your time.

Comment: Next time, make sure you tag the question with jQuery if you're using jQuery, it's annoying figuring out a plain JS solution when jQuery could be used for an answer in a fraction of the time. Also, either delete the question, or accepts an answer that works for you.

Comment: @adeneo I gave tag as Javascript while I was writing the question. It's not my fault if some readers answer to me in JQuery. Although, I fixed the tag after your "burning" advice.

Answer (score 2):

Just compare the text values, and hide

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.PriceBox');

for (var i = boxes.length; i--;) {
    var wTax = boxes[i].querySelector('div.priceWithoutTax'),
        sale = boxes[i].querySelector('div.salesPrice');

    if ( wTax.textContent.trim() == sale.textContent.trim() )
        wTax.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bx03ukrp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

By javascript:

Html(i added ids):

```
  <span id="salesPrice" class="salesPrice">20,00 €</span>
 <span id="priceWithoutTax" class="priceWithoutTax">20,00 €</span>
```

javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById("salesPrice").innerHTML==document.getElementById("priceWithoutTax").innerHTML){
document.getElementById("priceWithoutTax").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("priceWithoutTax").style.visibility= "hidden";
}
```

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: This is a string to string comparison. I would use `parseInt()` and `===` instead of `==` to get a more complete assessment.